# Android broadcastreceiver not triggering when app is not running or not launched and even when is running

Tags: android

I'm trying to do a background task even if the app is not running or wasn't launched when the phone is charging. But the code inside the onReceive method doesn't run.

This is the manifest:

```
<receiver
        android:name=".ChargingBroadcastReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
     <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED"/>
     </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
```

An the ChargingBroadcastReceiver class:

```
class ChargingBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

   override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
      // This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving an Intent broadcast.
      Toast.makeText(context.applicationContext, "Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
      Log.e("Test", "method onReceive()")
   }
}
```

I can't figure out what's wrong.

Is there any way trigger those actions (POWER_CONNECTED and POWER_DISCONNECTED) and run a background task inside the onReceive method without initiating or launch the app directly from the App Launcher?

Comment: Those actions are not invoked for broadcast receivers registered in the manifest. See https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions